# 'Chrome Url' not working

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have a link that I want to open the Bookmarks panel in Chrome. But when I click on it nothing happens. Please help!

```
<a href="chrome://bookmarks"></a>
```

Comment: What makes you think this would work in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this answer your question :

[image]

Comment: Still Not allowed to load local resource: chrome://bookmarks/